# Style Specific HTML tags in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-redux

I have a table and I'm trying to style it. That's what I've done so far:

```
                <tr>
                    <th> </th>
                    <th style={tstyle}>Canada</th>
                    <th style={tstyle}>US</th>
                    <th style={tstyle}>Total</th>
                </tr>
```

and then:

```
const tstyle = {
border: '1px solid #dddddd',
padding: '8px',
};
```

This works fine but I'm sure it's a better way to do that without repeating `style={tstyle}`. 
I tried doing like:

```
const styles = () => createStyles({
th: {
    color: 'blue',
},
```

There's no errors but it's not working.

Comment: Have you heard about the styled components ? it could help you [Styled-Components](https://www.styled-components.com/)

Comment: I suggest you use `Styled Components` for this.

Answer (score 1):

create-react-app supports CSS modules in the latest builds, check it out ;)

https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet

Also Styled Components is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using inline styles. Instead add below css style in your global css file

Set id to tr element

```
            <tr id="tr">
                <th> </th>
                <th>Canada</th>
                <th>US</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
```

For eg: app.css file

```
  #tr > th{
       border: '1px solid #dddddd';
       padding: '8px';
  }
```

If something else overrides th styles then set important

```
  #tr > th{
       border: '1px solid #dddddd !important';
       padding: '8px !important';
  }
```

So this css style will be applied across your application whoever you use th elements

Comment: but that will change all other tables since it's a really big project I can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

How about a custom functional component?

```
const style = {
border: '1px solid #dddddd',
padding: '8px',
};
const StyledTh = ({children: text}) => <th style={style}>{text}</th>
```

Usage:

```
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <StyledTh>Canada</StyledTh>
                    <StyledTh>US</StyledTh>
                    <StyledTh>Total</StyledTh>
                </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another suggestion: style it by using classes:

```
                    <tr>
                    <th> </th>
                    <th className={classes.tableCell} >Canada</th>
                    <th className={classes.tableCell}>US</th>
                    <th className={classes.tableCell}>Total</th>
                    </tr>
```

and then:

```
tableCell: {
    border: '1px solid #dddddd',
    padding: '8px',
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest using styled component.
you can define something like

```
const TableHeader = styled.th`    
      border: '1px solid #dddddd',
      padding: '8px',
    `;
```

and use it like:

```
<TableHeader></TableHeader>
<TableHeader>Canada</TableHeader>
....
```

Here is the link for getting started https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#getting-started

Answer (score -1):

Why not iterating over a styled th element?

```
headers = ['Canada', 'US', 'Total'];
const headerElements = headers.map(header => <th style={tstyle}>{header}</th>);
```

Then you call all your header elements

```
<tr>{headerElements}</tr>
```